# Can I propagate my Agave victoriae-reginae?

Tags: propagation, succulents

How do I propagate [*Agave victoriae-reginae*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agave_victoriae-reginae)?

Comment: See here: [Propagation of Cacti and Succulents](http://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/chiwonlee/plsc368/student/papers01/pneisen/Propagationofcactiandsucculents/Main%20Page.htm) via North Dakota State University

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Agave* is propagated by seed, offsets and tissue culture.

If it is your own plant that you want to propagate, you may have to wait twenty or thirty years for the plant to flower and provide seeds. You can, however, get *Agave victoriae-reginae* seed from [J. L Hudson](http://www.jlhudsonseeds.net/) and others perhaps. Germinating it in a flat or container of sterile sand at 70-80F (20-25C) be would be a good approach. Given *Agave*'s weird lifecycle, I would expect the germination to be inconsistent and to occur over a long period (several weeks). Xeric World Forums has an interesting [discussion on *Agave* and *Yucca* germination](http://www.xericworld.com/forums/agavaceae/1514-seed-advice.html) (page four is the best part).

*Agave* also produces small plantlets next to the main plant in much the same way that *Sempervivum* does. These plantlets are called offsets. *Agave victoriae-reginae* is very slow growing, so it produces few offsets, but they may occur occasionally. The main plant can be lifted, spring or early autumn, when the temperatures are moderate, and the offsets can be detached from the main plant. Try to keep as many root as possible with the offset. Also, leave the offset out to dry until any cuts that you have made have callused over. Then plant. Be cautious to avoid overwatering. A good description of the procedure can be found at [Mikes Exotics and Hardy Plants blog](http://bhutia2006.blogspot.com/2006/07/agaves-propagating-from-offsetsrunners.html). I have never propagated *Agave* this way, but I have with *Lewisia*.